# Using Jasmine with AJAX to load data does not seem to save it to the javascript class

Tags: javascript, ajax, jasmine, jasmine-ajax

I'm using Jasmine 2.8 with the jasmine-ajax plugin mock a jQuery getJSON call.  The callback is supposed to store the data back in the object.  I have a class structure as follows.

```
// --------- settings.js ------------
class settings{
  load(filename, callback){
     let self = this;
     $.getJSON(filename,funciton(d){
       let err = false;
       self._d = d;
       callback(d, err);
     }).fail(function(jqxhr, stat, err){
       let msg = ... build error message ...
       callback(msg, true);
     });
  }
}
// ------- myModule.js --------------
var Settings = require('settings');
class myModule{
  constructor(settingsFile){

    this._d = {};
    this._file = settingsFile; 
    this._settings = new Settings();
  }
  load(callback){
    let self = this;
    this._settings.load(this._file, function(d,err){
      if(!err){
        self._d = d;
        console.log(self._d); // prints the object
        callback('success');
      }
    });
  }
}


// ---------- myModuleSpec.js -------------
describe('manipulating data data', function(){
  beforeEach(function(){
    this.d = { pro1:'property1', prop2:{ foo:'bar' }}; 
    jasmine.Ajax.install();
    this.my = new MyModule('myfile.json');
    this.cb = new jasmine.createSpy();
    this.my.load(this.cb);
    let r = jasmine.Ajax.requests.mostRecent();
    r.respondWith({
      status:200,
      responseText.JSON.stringify(this.d);
    });
  });
  afterEach(function(){
    this.my = undefined;
    jasmine.Ajax.uninstall();
  });
  it('should have called the callback',function(){
    expect(this.cb).toHaveBeenCalled(); //passes
  });
  it('should contain the data', function(){
    console.log(this.my._d); // prints { } to the console
    expect(this.my._d).toEqual(jasmine.objectContaining(this.d)); // FAIL
  });
});
```

Jasmine returns the error message:
Expected({  }) to equal .

Putting in print statements into the code verifies the callback as been called and received the but when the test is run the data property (_d) is an empty object.

I'm using jasmine on the command line within nodejs.  I have a helper which loads a virtual dom using JSDOM and configures global.getJasmineRequireObj to configure jaxmine-ajax;

Thank you.